# how to set href modal using jquery with CI

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, continuous-integration

```
   <script>
        $(document).on("click", ".btn", function(){
            var dataID = $(this).data('id');
            var link = '<?php echo base_url()."admin/employees/deleteEmpOffice/";?>' + dataID;
            document.getElementById("deleteEmp").setAttribute("href",link);
        });
    </script>
```

This is my jquery

```
                            <tbody>                                 
                                <?php  if (is_array($empOffice) && count($empOffice)) : foreach ($empOffice as $row ) : ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <?php  echo $row->employee_id;?></td>
                                <td> <?php  echo $row->employee_first_name; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php  echo $row->employee_last_name; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php  echo $row->employee_position; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php  echo $row->employee_address; ?></td>
                                <td> <?php  echo $row->employee_mobile; ?></td>
                                <td class="center">
                                <a class="btn btn-info" href="#">
                                    <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>  
                                </a>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-setting"  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/vwDeleteModal" data-id="<?php echo  $row->employee_id;?>" >
                                    <i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i> 
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                        </tbody>
```

this is the html part with view and delete option where I set the data-id and is link to vwDeleteModal

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Please Confirm</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Are you sure?</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">

    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a id="deleteEmp" class="btn btn-primary">OK</a>
</div>
```

vwDeleteModal is loaded using `<?php echo $this->load->view();?>`

Now when I click Ok button in vwDeleteModal, the segment(4) in the url which supposedly the employee_id is declared undefined and i cant delete the employee
please can someone help me?!!

Answer (score 1):

To get the value of `data-id` try:

```
var dataID = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

instead of

```
var dataID = $(this).data('id');
```

EDIT:

Maybe this solves your problem:

```
 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-setting"  href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/vwDeleteModal/<?php echo  $row->employee_id;?>">
      <i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i> 
</a>
```

and

```
<a id="deleteEmp" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>">OK</a>
```

Comment: `$(this).data('id');` is the preferred way. why `attr()`?

Comment: i already change and nothings happen. now the url is like thishttp://localhost/GramConstruction/admin/employees/deleteEmpOffice/undefined

Comment: @Jai: Cause i dont know which jquery version he is using and jquery < 1.4.3 the `data` wont work ;)

Comment: yeah i just noticed now, can you help me Jai? thank you in advance

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=993258104023556&l=13c1a13ce7 i uploaded the print screen

Comment: could you please add a short fiddle with the necessary parts?

Comment: i could not. But the situation here was that when i click that Ok button it should delete the employee with the $employee_id which i used the uri helper t0 delete it($this->db->where('employee_id', $this->uri->segment(4));) that segement(4) should be the employee_id but it says undefined nad i cant delete the employee

Comment: Just a guess: your `ok`button doesn't have a attribute `data-id`, so if you click on it `data-id` must be `undefined`

Comment: I think im lost. i really dont know what to do. i can't delete and can't that segment(4)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function(){
        var dataID = $(this).data('id');
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#deleteEmp').attr('href',href);
    });
</script>
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-setting"  href="<?php echo base_url()."admin/employees/deleteEmpOffice/"."$row->employee_id";?>" data-id="<?php echo  $row->employee_id;?>">
<i class="halflings-icon white trash"></i> 
</a>
```

i solve it guys i just copy the link from a class ans set it to my modal. Thank you for your time